# How do I save a textarea value to a Rails session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a form with one input field -- a textarea -- and when the user submits the form I want to save the value of the textarea to the session. How do I do that, in Rails?

I'm using Devise, and the page I'm sending the user to after they submit the form is my Devise registration page.

So I imagine I need something like this in the registrations controller action:

```
session[:text_entered] = params()
```

...but Devise doesn't give me a registrations controller. Do I need to make one?

Am I stuck with a super long URL when the form gets submitted? Should this be a POST or a GET? How do I pass the textarea value to the registrations page without sending it as a URL parameter?

Sorry I'm a newbie. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What does the controller for the page the textarea is on look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have a controller for the page that the textarea is on, let's call it "SomethingsController." And the controller the form on that page submits to is, I gather, RegistrationsController. Instead of handling the submission of that form in RegistrationsController, what I would do is let SomethingsController handle it.

When you `POST` the form to SomethingsController (and yes, you should POST) it will fire the `create` action, and there you'll get the value from `params` (which is a Hash--you access its values with `[]`) and put it in `session`. Once you've done that you can redirect the user to the registration page. Something like this:

```
SomethingsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    if text = params[:text_area_name] && text.present?
      session[:text_entered] = text
      redirect_to new_user_registration_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "You didn't enter any text!"
      render :action => :new
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I had to remove the "&& text.present?" part but that totally worked and you explained it so well. Thank you!